# Multiple file upload with extra inputText

Tags: jsf, file-upload, primefaces

I need to implement the following:

1. multiple file upload in ajax style (without refreshing whole page)
2. description field per file
3. it must be done with JSF 2.0

There isn't problem to do 2 of 3 requirement in any combination. Multiple fileUpload with JSF 2.0 = PrimeFaces, multiple file upload + description is possible with JSF 2.2 because it has native upload element (I guess it can be ajaxed but didn't check it because I can't use it), but when I get all three requirements together I get stuck. 
On PrimeFaces's `p:fileUpload` there isn't description field and its simple mode doesn't support ajax.
JSF 2.0 doesn't have native fileUpload component. I can bind description field with PrimeFaces's `p:fileUpload` but I can't prevent from a user to choose multiple files and it cause that few files will be tied to one description.

So, is it possible to do multiple file upload in ajax style with description field in PrimeFaces and JSF 2.0?

Comment: You're using PrimeFaces 2.0 ?

Comment: No, I've only limitation regarding JSF version. I may use any Primeface if it's compatible with JSF 2.0

Comment: In my case I use 3.5 but considering to move on forward 5.0

Answer (score 7, accepted):

PrimeFaces upload is based on [blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload).

When `.serializeArray()` gets called, all the data inside that form would be serialized.

In that case you could override the PrimeFaces [implementation](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/master/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/primefaces/fileupload/fileupload.js#L1591) of the `add` option to append one extra input text for each file.

So the result would look like this:

[image: fileUpload with title]

Now that would be one extra line of code, exactly [here](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/master/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/primefaces/fileupload/fileupload.js#L1623):

```
.append('<td class="title"><label>Title: <input name="title['+ file.name +']"></label></td>') //the only modification we have to do
```

The extra input text is called `title[fileName]`, in that case you would get the value of the request parameter by the current file name.

```
public void handleFileUpload(FileUploadEvent event) {
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    Map map = context.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();
    String paramName = "title["+event.getFile().getFileName()+"]";
    String fileWithTitle = (String) map.get(paramName);            
}
```

Here's the full implementation of the `add` option (assuming your `widgetVar` is `fileUpload`)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   setTimeout(fileUpload, 1000);
})

function fileUpload() {

PF('fileUpload').jq.fileupload({
    add: function(e, data) {
        $this = PF('fileUpload');
        $this.chooseButton.removeClass('ui-state-hover ui-state-focus');
        if ($this.files.length === 0) {
            $this.enableButton($this.uploadButton);
            $this.enableButton($this.cancelButton);
        }

        if ($this.cfg.fileLimit && ($this.uploadedFileCount + $this.files.length + 1) > $this.cfg.fileLimit) {
            $this.clearMessages();
            $this.showMessage({
                summary: $this.cfg.fileLimitMessage
            });

            return;
        }

        var file = data.files ? data.files[0] : null;
        if (file) {
            var validMsg = $this.validate(file);

            if (validMsg) {
                $this.showMessage({
                    summary: validMsg,
                    filename: file.name,
                    filesize: file.size
                });
            }
            else {
                $this.clearMessages();                                                                               
                //the only modification we have to do
                var row = $('<tr></tr>').append('<td class="ui-fileupload-preview"></td>')
                        .append('<td>' + file.name + '</td>')
                        .append('<td class="title"><label>Title: <input name="title['+ file.name +']"></label></td>') 
                        .append('<td>' + $this.formatSize(file.size) + '</td>')
                        .append('<td class="ui-fileupload-progress"></td>')
                        .append('<td><button class="ui-fileupload-cancel ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-icon-only"><span class="ui-button-icon-left ui-icon ui-icon ui-icon-close"></span><span class="ui-button-text">ui-button</span></button></td>')
                        .appendTo($this.filesTbody);

                
                if ($this.isCanvasSupported() && window.File && window.FileReader && $this.IMAGE_TYPES.test(file.name)) {
                    var imageCanvas = $('<canvas></canvas')
                            .appendTo(row.children('td.ui-fileupload-preview')),
                            context = imageCanvas.get(0).getContext('2d'),
                            winURL = window.URL || window.webkitURL,
                            url = winURL.createObjectURL(file),
                            img = new Image();

                    img.onload = function() {
                        var imgWidth = null, imgHeight = null, scale = 1;

                        if ($this.cfg.previewWidth > this.width) {
                            imgWidth = this.width;
                        }
                        else {
                            imgWidth = $this.cfg.previewWidth;
                            scale = $this.cfg.previewWidth / this.width;
                        }

                        var imgHeight = parseInt(this.height * scale);

                        imageCanvas.attr({width: imgWidth, height: imgHeight});
                        context.drawImage(img, 0, 0, imgWidth, imgHeight);
                    }

                    img.src = url;
                }

                //progress
                row.children('td.ui-fileupload-progress').append('<div class="ui-progressbar ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuenow="0"><div class="ui-progressbar-value ui-widget-header ui-corner-left" style="display: none; width: 0%;"></div></div>');

                file.row = row;

                file.row.data('filedata', data);
                $this.files.push(file);

                if ($this.cfg.auto) {
                    $this.upload();
                }
            }
        }
    }});
}
```

Just included the above code in some `js` file and included it before the end of `</h:body>`

**Here's an** [online Demo](http://jsf.hatemalimam.com/DailyLab/fileUpload/main.xhtml).

*Note:* the only drag you might have in this approach, if the user has selected multiple files with ***the same exact name and extension*** you would get the first title twice!, for some this would be okay, since the user isn't supposed to upload identical files.

This is test on PrimeFaces 5.0 and Chrome.

Comment: It works! I have a few issues with a start-up script, but in general it works! Thank you very much!

Comment: What kind of issues ?

Comment: it doesn't work when I use it in overlay window, when I use it on main page it works excellent. I think that I need to write js function which will call your code when overlay is rendered, before this it just can't find this widget.

Comment: you need to make sure that the widgetVar is initialized and ready to be used, this is the main reason why I've used setTimeout in the document.ready. I imagine that your overlay is being rendered on the fly or partially, in that case as you said you should make sure that you call the code in right time.

Comment: I've done it and it works finally. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Hi! I'm trying to change JavaScript function in Primefaces's datatable  code but can't understand how to implement this? Can you please explain what's meaning of PF('fileUpload').jq.fileupload ? I tried to run in console PF('<widget_var_of_datatable>') but it returns undefined.

Comment: `PF('fileUpload')` is the javascript object of the component, `jq` is the jquery object, `fileupload` is the file upload javascript plugin object... you should take a look on javascript prototypes. @Anatoly