# Override a method from a Primefaces specific widget

Tags: javascript, primefaces, jsf-2

I want to overwrite a function of Primefaces datatable component. According to this question: [How do I find and/or override JavaScript in Primefaces component based on widgetVar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27551493/how-do-i-find-and-or-override-javascript-in-primefaces-component-based-on-widget) it is possible by using `PrimeFaces.widget.DataTable.prototype.`. But I want to override this function for one datatable only, not for all.

This does not work:

```
<p:dataTable widgetVar="myTable" ...>
</p:dataTable>
....
<script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function(){
           if (PF('myTable') !== undefined) {
                PF('myTable').jq.datatable({
                     showCellEditor: function (c) {
                         console.log('my function');
                     }
                 });
            }
         });
</script>
```

Is this how it is supposed to be done or am I completely wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Tested with one of my tables:

```js
PF('myTable').showCellEditor = function() {
    console.log('my function')
}
```

Don't forget to call the generic implementation if you need to:

```js
PF('myTable').showCellEditor = function() {
    console.log('my function')
    // call the generic implementation:
    PrimeFaces.widget.DataTable.prototype.showCellEditor.call(this);
}
```

**See also:**

- [Calling method using JavaScript prototype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/560829/calling-base-method-using-javascript-prototype)
- [Intro to Primefaces widgetvar](http://blog.hatemalimam.com/intro-to-primefaces-widgetvar/)