# Primefaces one poll "pause" another poll

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have two primefaces polls in the same page.

One of them (`pollLg`) has a longer interval time (30 seconds), while the other (`pollSm`) has a smaller interval (8 seconds).

When `pollLg` starts, I'd like `pollSm` to "pause" and then continue (remembering the time it was interrupted) after `pollLg` finishes its task.

If I call `PF('pollSm').stop()` and `PF('pollSm').start()` inside `pollLg` task, `pollSm` would be executed again only after 8 seconds.

For example, when the web page opens, I have:

```
pollSm executions: 8sec, 16sec, 24sec (pollLg will execute here and stop pollSm)
```

When `pollLg` finishes, then `pollSm` would execute only after 8 seconds, and not 2 seconds (it was interrupted with 6 seconds)

Is there any easy way to accomplish this?

Comment: _"Is there any easy way to accomplish this?"_ Define 'easy'... The javascript source of this component is open and can be overridden in a rather simple (or at least not too complex) way. And effectively this is not related to having two polls. Same would be for manually stopping/starting. The poll just has to 'remember' things.

Comment: @Kukeltje Well, easy would be a function that already existed, like a PF('poll').pause() or something related. So, I think i'll need to modify the source code of the component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me start by stating that the PrimeFaces source is open and can be easily used for inspecting (maybe undocumented) features. I did and noticed you can't easily do this in PrimeFaces in the sense that its poll component has a built-in feature. In the [javascipt source of the component](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/master/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/primefaces/poll/poll.js) you can see that it uses plain javascript timers.

So I started searching if you can do this easily in plain javascript and noticed there is no easy feature there either. Luckily there is an existing Q/A in StackOverflow about [pausing/resuming a timer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3969475/javascript-pause-settimeout) in javascript and it even has an answer [that is about repeating timers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3969475/javascript-pause-settimeout#answer-11196395).

If you combine this with [overriding (or extending) PrimeFaces widgets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39639532/override-a-method-from-a-primefaces-specific-widget), you can achieve what you want.

Comment: also that being said its probably not a bad feature request for the p:poll to have the stop() method track where it stopped and add a new resume() method to the Widget if someone want to resume().  The start() method would still start the timer over.

Comment: Thanks! I realized that I could do this without actually "pausing" the poll. But I'll definitely try to combine this with Primefaces widgets, though.