# How to listen to item removal event in p:chips?

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces

I'm new to PrimeFaces. I'm using [`p:chips`](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/chips.xhtml) component, I want to show a confirmation dialog before removing items from `p:chips`. Is there a direct way to do that, or how can I listen to the removal event using Java bean or JavaScript callbacks.

Comment: The short answer is there is no "pre" removal event hook.  There is an p:ajax event="itemUnselect" for using ajax to received the removed item.  To insert a hook for "pre" remove you will have to override the widget Javascript "removeItem" method which is an advanced topic like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39639532/override-a-method-from-a-primefaces-specific-widget

Answer (score -1):

you can use the onRemove property.

````html
<p-chip onRemove="removeFilterClick($event)"></p-chip>

then make an function.
```javascript
 removeFilterClick(event)
  var ref = this.dialogService.open(ConfirmModalComponent, {
  width: '650px',
  contentStyle: { 'max-height': '500px', overflow: 'auto' },
  styleClass: 'confirm-modal',
  baseZIndex: 10000,
  data: {
     message: "Are you sure you want to delete ?",
     successButtonText: 'Yes, Delete',
     cancelButtonText: 'Cancel',
  },
  });
````

Comment: The question is about PrimeFaces (Java, JSF, Jakarta Server Faces).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).