# Override show method from a Primefaces context menu

Tags: jsf, primefaces, contextmenu

Following the example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39639532/override-a-method-from-a-primefaces-specific-widget) I have tried to override the show() mehtod of a Primefaces  context menu.

Here my code:

```
       <p:tree value="#{myTreeBean.mainTreeRoot}" id="myTree>
                       <p:ajax event="contextMenu" listener="#{myTreeBean.onRightClickSelectListener}" oncomplete="PF('serverTreeMenuVar').show()"/>
[...]
        </p:tree>

    <p:contextMenu widgetVar="myTreeMenuVar" for="myTree" id="myTreeMenu" model="#{myBean.contextMenuModel}"></p:contextMenu>

     <script>

                    $( function() {
                        PF('myTreeMenuVar').show = function(e) {
                    console.log('my function');
                    // call the generic implementation:
                    PrimeFaces.widget.ContextMenu.prototype.show.call(this,e);
                }
                    });


    </script>
```

Unfortunately I get the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'pageX' of undefined

---

I'm using PF 7.0

Comment: Which version of PF do you use? Did you try PF 7?

Comment: Yes, I'm using PF 7.0

Comment: If you used `onclick="PF('myTreeMenuVar').show()"` not work?

Comment: For me it simply works his way. When rightclicking my component the menu occurs and it prints 'my function' to the console. Do you have any other component frame works, JQuery etc. in your project?

Comment: Argh. Sorry, I had this line in code that was causing the error:<p:ajax event="contextMenu" oncomplete="PF('myTreeMenuVar').show()"/> Thx for the help

Comment: Great you found the 'error', but then either add the original piece of code into the question in [mcve]  flavour and create an answer why it failed or remove the question...

Comment: ok, it's done. thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override was ok, the problem was caused by the following line:

```
  <p:ajax event="contextMenu" listener="#{myTreeBean.onRightClickSelectListener}" oncomplete="PF('serverTreeMenuVar').show()"/>
```

in particular from

```
oncomplete="PF('serverTreeMenuVar').show()"
```

Comment: So if you'd have started creating a [mcve] by removing a lot from your code including this line, you'd have immediately seen that it was not related to the overriding... That is what [mcve]'s are for... Narrow things down, rooot cause analysis