# Overriding primefaces bindEvents function

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces

I'm trying to change dialogs behavior in primefaces so I will be able to create a hierarchy of dialogs rather than having the last clicked dialog shown on top.
So I tried to override some javascript functions such as moveToTop(), _show() and bindEvents () of the object PrimeFaces.widget.Dialog .
The problem is a couldn't override the bindEvents () function or remove it :

```
PF('dialog'). bindEvents =function(){}
```

Any help will be appreciated..

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I find and/or override JavaScript in Primefaces component based on widgetVar?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27551493/how-do-i-find-and-or-override-javascript-in-primefaces-component-based-on-widget)

Comment: Make google your friend…