# Is there a way to catch livescroll event in a Primefaces Datatable?

Tags: ajax, events, scroll, primefaces, datatable

I have a datatable with livescroll in my view, and an ajaxstatus component. With most of the components I avoid firing the ajaxstatus dialog by setting:

```
<p:ajax event="someEvent" global=false\>
```

in the ajax event, but I don't find a way to do the same with a datatable since there are 'page' and 'sort' events but not a 'scroll' event. Any ideas how to avoid this situation?

Comment: Did you check the source... it is open. Did you check the documentation? And iirc you can set a global `global='false'`

Comment: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/65, so the only way is to create a patch... Code is fairly easy to understand

Comment: I checked the documentation and it seems there is no way to catch that event. I'll try adapting the code. Thanks.

Comment: I'll have a quick look too and maybe give you some hints. Do you need specific info in the event?

Comment: Or do you just want to disable the 'global' ajax feature? The latter is not to difficult

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you 'just' want achieve a `global="false"` like behaviour, the easiest thing to do is to [override](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27551493/how-do-i-find-and-or-override-javascript-in-primefaces-component-based-on-widget/27564325) the [relevant function in the PrimeFaces Datatable.js function](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/16bad3f9a0dfa82d50c58b847a26a872be4aba5d/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/primefaces/datatable/datatable.js#L1296) and add a `global: false` in the options of the ajax call that is made under the hood.

This can be done by including the following javascript

```
PrimeFaces.widget.DataTable.prototype.loadLiveRows: function() {
    if(this.liveScrollActive||(this.scrollOffset + this.cfg.scrollStep > this.cfg.scrollLimit)) {
        return;
    }

    this.liveScrollActive = true;
    this.scrollOffset += this.cfg.scrollStep;

    //Disable scroll if there is no more data left
    if(this.scrollOffset === this.cfg.scrollLimit) {
        this.shouldLiveScroll = false;
    }

    var $this = this,
    options = {
        source: this.id,
        process: this.id,
        update: this.id,
        global: false,    /* Added this so the global is not triggered */
        formId: this.cfg.formId,
        params: [{name: this.id + '_scrolling', value: true},
                        {name: this.id + '_skipChildren', value: true},
                        {name: this.id + '_scrollOffset', value: this.scrollOffset},
                        {name: this.id + '_encodeFeature', value: true}],
        onsuccess: function(responseXML, status, xhr) {
            PrimeFaces.ajax.Response.handle(responseXML, status, xhr, {
                widget: $this,
                handle: function(content) {
                    //insert new rows
                    this.updateData(content, false);

                    this.liveScrollActive = false;
                }
            });

            return true;
        },
        oncomplete: function(xhr, status, args, data) {
            if(typeof args.totalRecords !== 'undefined') {
                $this.cfg.scrollLimit = args.totalRecords;
            }

            $this.loadingLiveScroll = false;
            $this.allLoadedLiveScroll = ($this.scrollOffset + $this.cfg.scrollStep) >= $this.cfg.scrollLimit;

            // reset index of shift selection on multiple mode
            $this.originRowIndex = null;
        }
    };

    PrimeFaces.ajax.Request.handle(options);
},
```

There unfortunately is no way to partially overide and reuse most (all) of the existing function. I thought you could override the `global` in a global way so no ajax call triggers the global status. I can unfortunately not find a reference on how to do that anymore.

You can however override the default behaviour in absence of a `global` setting by overriding [Primefaces.ajax.Request.handle](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/3a6be21bd0192f72019d4ce1ac6c7380735a34de/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/primefaces/core/core.ajax.js#L243)

```
handle: function(cfg, ext) {
    cfg.ext = ext;

    if (PrimeFaces.settings.earlyPostParamEvaluation) {
        cfg.earlyPostParams = PrimeFaces.ajax.Request.collectEarlyPostParams(cfg);
    }

    if(cfg.async) {
        PrimeFaces.ajax.Request.send(cfg);
    }
    else {
        PrimeFaces.ajax.Queue.offer(cfg);
    }
},
```

By adding an explicit setting of `cfg.global` to false when absent

```
var orgHandle = PrimeFaces.ajax.Request.handle;
Primefaces.ajax.Request.prototype.handle = function(cfg, ext) {
     var global = (cfg.global === false || cfg.global === undefined) ? false : true;
     cfg.global = global;
     orgHandle(cfg, ext);
}
```

Take your pick.

Comment: Sorry for such a newbie question but how should I incorporate this code? Should it be added to the .xhtml  as any other js script? I'm refering to the PrimeFaces.widget.DataTable.prototype.loadLiveRows function ... Thank you so much for your answer!

Comment: Yes, but make sure it comes after all other PrimeFaces scripts. I'll see on on monday if I can find a duplicate Q/A, I'm sure there is... cheers